# FadeIn header with .css() and .fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I want to fadeIn my header while scrolling through the page.
This is what I've got so far, everything works except the .fadeIn().

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 120 ) {
        if( !fixed ) {
            fixed = true;
            $('.mini-logo').css({display:'block'});
            $(' header ').css({background:'#323232'});
        }
    } else {
        if( fixed ) {
            fixed = false;
            $('.mini-logo').css({display:'none'});
            $(' header ').css({background:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps if you actually used `.fadeIn()` in your example it would work better? :)

Comment: Haha yeah ;). I'm not sure where I should put it.

Comment: I'm sure if you put an example of your HTML as well in a JSFiddle, someone will sort it out quickly. Please clarify when you want it to fade in/out?

Comment: The <header> tag is a HTML5 tag and it's different from the <head> tag.

Comment: Excuse last comment... Too early and no coffee yet. Can you provide your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something simple like this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eYcL4/:

```
var fixed = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 120 ) {
        if( !fixed ) {
            fixed = true;
            $('.mini-logo').css({display:'block'});
            $('header').css({background:'#323232'});
            $('header').fadeOut();
        }
    } else {
        if( fixed ) {
            fixed = false;
            $('.mini-logo').css({display:'none'});
            $('header').css({background:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'});
            $('header').fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

But the immediate problem is that fading out the header changes the height of the content (header collapses to 0 height when hidden).

Please explain the effect you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `$('.mini-logo').css({display:'none'});` use `$('.mini-logo').fadeOut();`
And instead of `$('.mini-logo').css({display:'block'});` use `$('.mini-logo').fadeIn();`

Comment: I could be wrong, but based on the question he wanted to fade the header, not just the logo (which presumably is in the header).